Impact of Skew on Bermudan Swaptions
I'm trying to understand the impact of different skew assumptions on the pricing of Bermudan swaptions, e.g. 10NC1 struck at K%.
It is often stated that the price of the Bermudan depends primarily on correlation between co-terminal swap rates and the volatility of underlying co-terminal K% European swaptions to which most people tend to calibrate their model.
Does this mean the skew is a second order impact? For example, for a 3% receiver, what would be the impact of switching between Black Karasinski and Hull White, when both are calibrated to 3% co-terminal European swaptions. Any literature on this or general intuition on the skew impact would be very interesting.
Thanks!
